# Set window size in Python openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

When creating a new spreadsheet using openpyxl, the first time the new spreadsheet is opened in Excel, it appears full-screen, completely filling the display.  How can I set the geometry of the window, either in terms of columns and rows, or screen location and window dimensions, so that it opens in a smaller window.

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly, I have tried to many things to remember.

Comment: I have found something potentially useful (BookView). But, it does notjing.      view = BookView(activeTab=0, windowHeight=400, windowWidth=500, showSheetTabs=False)
    ws.bookViews = view

Answer (score 1):

BookView is the right class. The problem is how to call it and set the view.

```
from openpyxl.workbook.views import BookView
...
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    view = [BookView(xWindow=0, yWindow=0, windowWidth=18140, windowHeight=15540)]
    wb.views = view
```

For the definition of: xWindow, yWindow, windowWidth, windowHeight and more, see [the MS Excell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.workbookview?view=openxml-2.8.1) Note, the values are in *twips* (1/20 of a point)